# Xamarin Forms - Android project doesnt deploy from Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019, adb

The Android project doesnt deploy from Visual studio to Samsung Tab.
Initially the output shows deploying to device, after 2 minutes, it changes to Ready state and doesnt deploy even after 30 mins.

Below is the part of output I get repeatedly[couldnt attach whole output]. Can anyone help me why this happens? Thanks in Advance

[image]

```
[aot-compiler stdout] Added 0 methods from profile.
[aot-compiler stdout] Compiled: 0/0
[aot-compiler stdout] Executing the native assembler: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
dk\aarch64-linux-android-as"   -o C:\_release\100\aot\arm64-v8a\Rg.Plugins.Popup.dll\temp.s.o C:\_release\100\aot\arm64-v8a\Rg.Plugins.Popup.dll\temp.s
[aot-compiler stdout] Executing the native linker: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
dk\aarch64-linux-android-ld" -Bsymbolic -shared -o C:\_release\100\aot\arm64-v8a\libaot-Rg.Plugins.Popup.dll.so.tmp  C:\_release\100\aot\arm64-v8a\Rg.Plugins.Popup.dll\temp.s.o 
[aot-compiler stdout] JIT time: 0 ms, Generation time: 8 ms, Assembly+Link time: 2638 ms.
[aot-compiler stdout] Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly C:\_release\100\android\assets\ABC_Mobile.dll
[aot-compiler stdout] AOTID AD8A55E2-5D90-DBD2-20AA-0EB5F30CA8D6
[aot-compiler stdout] Using profile data file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\startup-xf.aotprofile'
[aot-compiler stdout] Added 0 methods from profile.
[aot-compiler stdout] Compiled: 16/16
[aot-compiler stdout] Executing the native assembler: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
dk\aarch64-linux-android-as"   -o C:\_release\100\aot\arm64-v8a\ABC_Mobile.dll\temp.s.o C:\_release\100\aot\arm64-v8a\ABC_Mobile.dll\temp.s
[aot-compiler stdout] Executing the native linker: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
dk\aarch64-linux-android-ld" -Bsymbolic -shared -o C:\_release\100\aot\arm64-v8a\libaot-ABC_Mobile.dll.so.tmp  C:\_release\100\aot\arm64-v8a\ABC_Mobile.dll\temp.s.o 
[aot-compiler stdout] JIT time: 108 ms, Generation time: 139 ms, Assembly+Link time: 4334 ms.
[aot-compiler stdout] Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly C:\_release\100\android\assets\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll
[aot-compiler stdout] AOTID DDEE118B-BBA5-7A06-5B54-EE9EB049494A
[aot-compiler stdout] Using profile data file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\startup-xf.aotprofile'
[aot-compiler stdout] Added 801 methods from profile.
[aot-compiler stdout] Compiled: 1573/1574
[aot-compiler stdout] Executing the native assembler: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
dk\aarch64-linux-android-as"   -o C:\_release\100\aot\arm64-v8a\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll\temp.s.o C:\_release\100\aot\arm64-v8a\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll\temp.s
[aot-compiler stdout] Executing the native linker: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
dk\aarch64-linux-android-ld" -Bsymbolic -shared -o C:\_release\100\aot\arm64-v8a\libaot-Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll.so.tmp  C:\_release\100\aot\arm64-v8a\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll\temp.s.o 
[aot-compiler stdout] JIT time: 1298 ms, Generation time: 1109 ms, Assembly+Link time: 2990 ms..
```

the adb temp file content:

> adb starting (pid 15236) --- adb I 05-09 11:59:41 15236 11944 main.cpp:62] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 adb I 05-09 11:59:41 15236 11944 main.cpp:62] Version 30.0.4-6686687 adb I 05-09 11:59:41 15236 11944 main.cpp:62] Installed as C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.EXE adb I 05-09 11:59:41 15236 11944 main.cpp:62] adb I 05-09 11:59:41 15236 11944 auth.cpp:417] adb_auth_init... adb I 05-09 11:59:41 15236 11944 auth.cpp:152] loaded new key from 'C:\Users\name.android\adbkey' with fingerprint 69E79BFD0AF8309554998A71DE062E adb I 05-09 12:00:29 15236 14372 transport.cpp:325] A52R0GHX: read thread spawning adb I 05-09 12:00:29 15236 11976 transport.cpp:297] A52R0GHX: write thread spawning adb I 05-09 12:00:29 15236 11944 transport.cpp:1527] fetching keys for transport A52R0GHX adb I 05-09 12:00:29 15236 11944 auth.cpp:469] Calling send_auth_response adb I 05-09 12:00:29 15236 11944 adb.cpp:124] A52R0GHX: offline adb I 05-09 12:00:30 15236 14372 transport.cpp:329] A52R0GHX: read failed: Input/output error adb I 05-09 12:00:30 15236 14372 transport.cpp:810] A52R0GHX: connection terminated: read failed adb I 05-09 12:00:30 15236 11944 adb.cpp:124] A52R0GHX: offline adb I 05-09 12:00:30 15236 11944 transport.cpp:914] destroying transport A52R0GHX adb I 05-09 12:00:30 15236 11944 transport.cpp:400] BlockingConnectionAdapter(A52R0GHX): stopping adb I 05-09 12:00:30 15236 11944 transport.cpp:418] BlockingConnectionAdapter(A52R0GHX): stopped adb I 05-09 12:00:30 15236 11944 transport.cpp:283] BlockingConnectionAdapter(A52R0GHX): destructing adb I 05-09 12:00:30 15236 11944 transport.cpp:392] BlockingConnectionAdapter(A52R0GHX): already stopped adb I 05-09 12:00:32 15236 12392 transport.cpp:325] A52R0GHX: read thread spawning adb I 05-09 12:00:32 15236 15672 transport.cpp:297] A52R0GHX: write thread spawning adb I 05-09 12:00:32 15236 11944 transport.cpp:1527] fetching keys for transport A52R0GHX adb I 05-09 12:00:32 15236 11944 auth.cpp:469] Calling send_auth_response adb I 05-09 12:00:32 15236 11944 adb.cpp:124] A52R0GHX: offline adb I 05-09 13:17:48 15236 12392 transport.cpp:329] A52R0GHX: read failed: Input/output error adb I 05-09 13:17:48 15236 12392 transport.cpp:810] A52R0GHX: connection terminated: read failed adb I 05-09 13:17:48 15236 11944 adb.cpp:124] A52R0GHX: offline adb I 05-09 13:17:48 15236 11944 transport.cpp:914] destroying transport A52R0GHX adb I 05-09 13:17:48 15236 11944 transport.cpp:400] BlockingConnectionAdapter(A52R0GHX): stopping adb I 05-09 13:17:48 15236 11944 transport.cpp:418] BlockingConnectionAdapter(A52R0GHX): stopped adb I 05-09 13:17:48 15236 11944 transport.cpp:283] BlockingConnectionAdapter(A52R0GHX): destructing adb I 05-09 13:17:48 15236 11944 transport.cpp:392] BlockingConnectionAdapter(A52R0GHX): already stopped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by **unchecking** **Enable Startup Tracing** inside the Android option, which sets AndroidEnableProfiledAot to false.